# Typeorem parameter not equal to several values

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

How can I get a query in Typeorm that will get result like this:

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id <> 3 and id <> 8 and id <> 23;`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this correctly is by using the QueryBuilder class in Typeorm. You can read more about it in the link below:

[TypeORM QueryBuilder](https://%20https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder)

For your specific case you can use the following code snippet to achieve the query that you have mentioned:

```js
async function getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
      const userRepository = getConnection().getRepository(User);
      
      const query = userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
        .where('user.id <> :id1', { id1: 3 })
        .andWhere('user.id <> :id2', { id2: 8 })
        .andWhere('user.id <> :id3', { id3: 23 });

      const users = await query.getMany();
      return users;
}
```